# JavaScript: Appending data from a 2D array in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I have a 2 dimensional array that I am attempting to append it's values. I have provided 2 code snippets; First one is an example of what I am attempting to accomplish with the second code snippet. The first code snippet me appending data manually for every single index.

Essentially I am attempting to create a list that looks like

1. Online   3.2
2. Appointment   2.9
3. Store   1.8

which is why in my first code snippe I do a `col-md-7` first for the index with the title and then follow up with a `col-md-5` for the index with the decimal like this :

```
htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
htmlOutput += "<p> 1. " + array[0][0] + "</p>";
htmlOutput += "</div>";

htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-5 '>";
htmlOutput += "<p>" + array[0][1]+ "</p>";
htmlOutput += "</div>";
```

---

In my second code snippet, I am attempting to loop through my array and increment the data but I am unable to seperate the indexs in the array for a example my current result is :

```
<div class='col-md-5'><p>Online,3.2</p></div>
<div class='col-md-5'><p>Appointment,2.9</p></div>
<div class='col-md-5'><p>Store,1.8</p></div>
<div class='col-md-5'><p>Date,4.1</p></div>
<div class='col-md-5'><p>Phone,1.2</p></div>
```

Where index 0 and 1 are being returned together in one div. My expected outcome is to have these indexes separate and have my return be something like this

```
 <div class='col-md-7'><p>Online</p></div> 
 <div class='col-md-5'><p>3.2</p></div>   // index 0 

<div class='col-md-7'><p>Appointment</p></div> 
 <div class='col-md-5'><p>2.9</p></div>     // index 1
```

```js
let htmlOutputArray = ""

const array = [
["Online", 3.2 ], 
["Appointment", 2.9],
["Store", 1.8],
["Date", 4.1],
["Phone", 1.2]
] ;


let htmlOutput = ""

htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-6'>";

 htmlOutput += "<div class='row'>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p> 1. " + array[0][0] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-5 '>";
    htmlOutput += "<p>" + array[0][1]+ "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p> 2. " + array[1][0] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-5'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p>" + array[1][1] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p> 3. " + array[2][0] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-5'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p>" + array[2][1] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p> 4. " + array[3][0] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-5'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p>" + array[3][1] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p> 5. " + array[4][0] + "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "<div class='col-md-5'>";
    htmlOutput += "<p>" + array[4][1]+ "</p>";
    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "</div>";

    htmlOutput += "</div>";
    
    htmlOutputArray += htmlOutput;    // concat all previously rendered html outputs

$("#appendData").html(htmlOutputArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='appendData'> </div>
```

```js
let text = ""

const array = [
["Online", 3.2 ], 
["Appointment", 2.9],
["Store", 1.8],
["Date", 4.1],
["Phone", 1.2]
] ;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    
    text += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
    text += "<p>" + array[0][i] + "</p>";
    text += "</div>";

}

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the snippet below, you were passing the `i` index into the second dimension of the array instead of the first.

I've switched to [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax because it's a bit more concise in this case.

I've also used the `i` index to output the "1.", "2." before the titles.

```js
let text = ""

const array = [
  ["Online", 3.2 ], 
  ["Appointment", 2.9],
  ["Store", 1.8],
  ["Date", 4.1],
  ["Phone", 1.2]
]

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    text += `<div class='col-md-7'><p>${i + 1}. ${array[i][0]}</p></div>`
    text += `<div class='col-md-5'><p>${array[i][1]}</p></div>`
}

// console.log(text)
document.getElementById('appendData').innerHTML = text
```

```html
<div id='appendData'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, just to get a little more detail and understand everything fully. The `<p>${i + 1}.` is to increment + 1 every time which then returns the results 1., 2.. 3. etc.. did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Not quite correect, the `<p>${i + 1}.` is what outputs the `1. `, `2. `, etc. It's taking the index of the loop `i` and adding 1 to it because the loop starts at index 0 (`let i = 0`). Without the `+ 1` it would be be `0. `, `1. `, etc

Comment: Oh re-reading your question I think you may have actually understood correctly, I just interpreted incorrectly 

Answer (score 0):

`i` should be the first index, not the second index. Then you need to concatenate `[i][0]` and `[i][1]`, just like in your expanded code.

```js
let text = ""

const array = [
  ["Online", 3.2],
  ["Appointment", 2.9],
  ["Store", 1.8],
  ["Date", 4.1],
  ["Phone", 1.2]
];


for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  text += "<div class='col-md-7'>";
  text += "<p>" + array[i][0] + "</p>";
  text += "</div>";
  text += "<div class='col-md-5 '>";
  text += "<p>" + array[i][1] + "</p>";
  text += "</div>";
}

console.log(text)
```